# Packing two C struct into a uint8_t pointer to write into DataFlash

Tags: c, pointers, struct, arm

I have two C structs that need to be saved into a memory block in a DataFlash (AT45). I can easily save one such struct by:

**For One Struct**

```
struct_name a;
struct_name * data;
data = &a;
struct_name read_buffer;

flash_write( &write_address, (uint8_t *)data, sizeof(a) ); //pack
flash_read( &read_address, (uint8_t *)read_buffer, sizeof(a) ); //unpack
```

The packing and unpacking (without padding) are easy for one struct. How do I do it if I have `two structs` to be packed?

**For Two Struct**

```
struct_name1 a;
struct_name2 b;
/** Pack them into one and pass reference to flash_write method */
/**    Also how do I unpack                                     */
```

I was trying to have a `struct` which both `struct_name1` and `struct_name2`. But confused on how to do it.

Comment: Don't abuse structures to do serialization. Instead, create byte array for buffer, then convert each struct member to bytes manually, and finally write buffer to flash.

Comment: If the structure is packed can't it be used for serialization? I'm sorry, but I don't understand why I shouldn't be using structs for serialization.

Comment: 1) Structures require extra work to handle endianness. 2) Structures don't support variable width content. 3) Structures don't handle pointers gracefully. 4) Structures require non-standard extensions to handle padding issues. Taking care of all of this requires extra code, and that time could have been spent writing the portable code in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both structs can be member of an array, it will be trivial:

```
struct_name both[2];  // both[0] is a and both[1] is b
// store data in both[0] and both[1]
...

struct_name read_buffer[2];
flash_write( &write_address, (uint8_t *)both, sizeof(both) ); //pack
flash_read( &read_address, (uint8_t *)read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer) ); //unpack
```

If they are not initially member of the same array, you can copy them:

```
struct_name both[2];
both[0] = a;
both[1] = b;

struct_name read_buffer[2];
flash_write( &write_address, (uint8_t *)both, sizeof(both) ); //pack
flash_read( &read_address, (uint8_t *)read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer) ); //unpack
```

---

If they are different structs, just use a struct as aggregate as shown in notan's answer.

Comment: They are not the same structs. If they where I could have written twice and read twice to unpack. Thanks, but not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Understood from notan's answer. But marking your's as the answer. Thanks a ton. Do you know why user694733 asked me not to use structs for serialization?

Answer (score 2):

Pack both structs into a struct and use that:

```
struct_name1 a;
struct_name2 b;

struct struct_for_both
{
    struct_name1 a;
    struct_name2 b;
} both = {a,b}; // initialize by copying Contents of a and b

struct_for_both read_buffer;

flash_write( &write_address, (uint8_t *)&both, sizeof(both) ); //pack
flash_read( &read_address, (uint8_t *)read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer) ); //unpack
```